My Project isn't redeploying on Vercel.com with the up-to-date version from github
This was working for me but suddenly stopped. I have my next.js project on vercel.com. When I want to update my code I usually execute the following in visual studio code cmd:
git init
git add .
git commit -m 'ready for deployment'
git remote add origin <github URL, e.g. https://github.com/drattansingh/market.git>
git push -f origin master

Upon executing the last line I normally see a deployment automatically refreshing in the deployments section in vercel.com. However it stopped working and I don't know how to refresh my project. I've checked github and I'm seeing the updated code however vercel.com is still showing a previous version.
I also tried to do it manually:

But when I click redeploy, it's redeploying (avg 1.5 minutes) but still showing the previous version. Anyone knows how to resolve this issue?
Update
I got it working, don't know why it worked whole of last year and suddenly stopped. I had to enter my github email in git bash and after it redeployed fine.
see more here

What happens when you run the vercel command in your project?

@Ethan when I run the above commands nothing happens in vercel. Normally I'd see my project automatically redeploying but now I see nothing

@Ethan I now got it working. It seems I had to add my email to Git Bash and after it started working fine again, thank for your help
